# Настройка VISUAL CODE под C++

Tags: c++, компиляция, visual-studio-code

Скачал VISUAL CODE (не студию, а CODE), не компилирует C++. Ютуб смотрел, гуглил, ничего толкового. Спасибо. 
Почему VISUAL CODE - решил попробовать, хотя есть Студия 2010. Спасибо. Можно подробное описание или ссылку на мануал. Спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вы имеете в виду `visual studio code`? Так она и не должна вам ничего компилировать. Изначально - это просто текстовый редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса. Может и есть плагины, позволяющие удобно компилировать `c++` в `studio code`, однако лучше используйте полноценную студию для таких целей.

Comment: А он и не будет компилировать, это редактор, а не компилятор. Нужно установить компилятор и настроить систему сборки. Хотя, наверно проще поставить линукс, где этот редактор настривается быстрее и работает проще. И под маком тоже.

Comment: Можете подсказать как установить и подключить компилятор. Скачал MIN GW.

Comment: Можете подсказать как установить и подключить компилятор. Скачал MIN GW, а дальше в настройках запутался.

Comment: @9014426 [вот](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp), пожалуйста